# Wrong Joomla links on facebook

Tags: facebook, joomla, hyperlink, share

friend asked me to help him out with his Joomla website. Here is the problem. He turned off Plugin System Cache and in Global Config he turned off cache in Cache settings and when he posts links on his articles on Facebook everything is fine. He needed to turn on those caches due to website crashes but now when he links article on Facebook Article name is something random from site and not actual article name. He tried Facebook Debug option and this was error

```
More Than One OG URL Specified: 
Object at URL 'http://www.madbarz.com/news/614-not-your-average-mamas-workout' of type       

'website' is invalid because it specifies multiple 'og:url' values: 
 http://www.madbarz.com/news/614-not-your-average-mamas-workout,     
 http://www.madbarz.com/news/565-hannibal-for-king-compilation,   
 http://www.madbarz.com/add-team.
```

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the "post to facebook" code is being cached once instead of once per page.

This most likely depends on it being added as a module (as opposed to a plugin, which would cause no trouble), and the module doesn't take into account proper caching techniques.

Since having page caching and global cache on is desirable, you may be able to get around this just setting the module's cache to "Do not cache": it will still be cached by the system page cache, but that cache is built once per each page so you'll be fine.

The multiple headers could be an issue generated by the same cause.

If this still doesn't solve the issue, look into the module's code; here you can find some info on setting up a module to cache correctly: http://www.fasterjoomla.com/joomla-dev/programmare-un-modulo-joomla-per-utilizzare-la-cache

The reason the site crashes with cache turned off should be studied: it's not normal and you don't want to run a site under those conditions, it's not safe.  There could be something really really wrong and you might end up wasting months to build linkbacks only to find they all become invalid at some point.